# How to null out exceptions in an htmlChecker

Tags: python-3.x, stack

While this is a project assignment for class I am trying to understand how to do a specific part of the project.

I need to go through an html file and check if all the opening statements are matched to closing statements. Further, they must be in the correct order and this must be checked using a stack I've implemented. As of right now I am working on extracting each tag from the file. The tough part seems to be the two exceptions that I am working on here. The 
 and the . I need these tags to be removed so the program doesn't read them as an opening or closing statement.

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items[-1]


 def getTag(file):
    EXCEPTIONS = ['br/', 'meta']
    s = Stack()
    balanced = True
    i = 0
    isCopying = False
    currentTag = ''
    isClosing = False
    while i < len(file) and balanced:
        if symbol == "<":
            if i < (len(file) - 1) and file[i + 1] == "/":
                i = i + 1  
                isClosing == True
            isCopying == True
        if symbol == ">":
            if isClosing == True:
                top = s.pop()
                if not matches(top, symbol):
                    balanced = False
            else:
                **strong text**
                s.push(currentTag)
            currentTag = ''
            isCopying == False 
        if isCopying == True:
            currentTag += symbol
```

The code reads in the file and goes letter by letter to search for `<string>`. If it exists it pushes it on to the stack. The `matches` functions checks to see if the closing statement equals the opening statement. The exceptions list is the ones I have to check for that will screw up the placing of the strings on the stack. I am having a tough time trying to incorporate them into my code. Any ideas? Before I push on to the stack I should go through a filter system to see whether that statement is valid or not valid. A basic if statement should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your requirements correctly, you're going about this very awkwardly. What you're really looking to do is [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) your file, and so the first thing you should do is get all the tokens in your file, and *then* check to see if it is a valid ordering of tokens.

Tokenization means you parse through your file and find all valid tokens and put them in an ordered list. A valid token in your case is any string length that starts with a `<` and ends with a `>`. You can safely discard the rest of the information I think? It would be easiest if you had a `Token` class to contain your token types.

Once you have that ordered list of tokens it is *much easier* to determine if they are a 'correct ordering' using your stack:

> is_correct_ordering algorithm:

```
For each element in the list
  if the element is an open-token, put it on the stack
  if the element is a close-token
    if the stack is empty return false
    if the top element of the stack is a matching close token
      pop the top element of the stack
    else return false
  discard any other token
If the stack is NOT empty, return false
Else return true
```

Naturally, having a reasonable `Token` class structure makes things easy:

```
class Token:
    def matches(t: Token) -> bool:
        pass  # TODO Implement

    @classmethod
    def tokenize(token_string: str) -> Token:
        pass  # TODO Implement to return the proper subclass instantiation of the given string

class OpenToken:
    pass

class CloseToken:
    pass

class OtherToken:
    pass
```

This breaks the challenge into two parts: first parsing the file for all valid tokens (easy to validate because you can hand-compare your ordered list with what you see in the file) and then validating that the ordered list is correct. Note that here, too, you can simplify what you're working on by delegating work to a sub-routine:

```
def tokenize_file(file) -> list:
    token_list = []

    while i < len(file):
        token_string, token_end = get_token(file[i:])
        token_list.append = Token.tokenize(token_string)
        i = i + token_end  # Skip to the end of this token

    return token_list

def get_token(file) -> tuple:
    # Note this is a naive implementation. Consider the edge case:
    #    <img src="Valid string with >">
    token_string = ""
    for x in range(len(file)):
        token_string.append(file[x])
        if file[x] == '>':
            return token_string, x
    # Note that this function will fail if the file terminates before you find a closing tag!
```

The above should turn something like this:

```
<html>Blah<meta src="lala"/><body><br/></body></html>
```

Into:

```
[OpenToken('<html>'),
 OtherToken('<meta src="lala"/>'),
 OpenToken('<body>'),
 OtherToken('<br/>'),
 CloseToken('</body>'),
 CloseToken('</html>')]
```

Which can be much more easily handled to determine correctness.

Obviously this isn't a complete implementation of your problem, but hopefully it will help straighten out the awkwardness you've chosen with your current direction.

Comment: Ah I've never heard of tokenizing before. That makes sense if I was trying to target certain string cases in the file.

Comment: You *are* trying to target certain string cases.

Comment: The awkwardness in your attempt, though, is that you're trying to do everything at once. You really need to break out these requirements to make it EASY to see that one token is something you care about and another isn't.